# How to configure Samba to allow root user for full control to the particular share?

Tags: linux, samba, server-message-block, smbfs, smb-conf

$(subj), it appears to be what root user is denied by default for all of the shares.
I'm trying to reproduce Windows administrative share.

Answer (score 24):

Do you have a password set in Samba (not in the system passwd file) for root ? You should be able to set such a password by running `smbpasswd -a root`.

Comment: Slap forehead, vote up and accept! I completely forgot what there is no common AAA in the Linux!

Comment: Yes, this one needs marked as accepted

Answer (score 11):

You should be putting up your smb.conf so that we can actually assess the problem.
Anyway here's a hint:

```
   invalid users = root
```

is part of the default smb.conf.

Well then.
Is root a valid smbuser, yet?
Then try explicitly allowing root :

```
valid users = root
```

And try something like this:

```
[config]
    comment = Admin Config Share  - Whatever
    path = /
    valid users = someusers, somegroup
    force user = root
    force group = root
    admin users = someusers, somegroup   
    writeable = Yes
```

Comment: Does it have to be explicitly specified option or implicitly assumed? My `smb.conf` isnt "from-scratch" and does not contain any `valid users` or `invalid users` parameters at all.

Comment: Hmm, also, according to [doc](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#INVALIDUSERS) there is no invalid users by default.

Comment: See edited post.

Answer (score 1):

if you can't access two users, one for a regular user and the other for a root, you need to alias the netbios in smb.conf file so that windows sees them as two servers.  Then access each with a different user id.  You may also add to the windows' host file the same server's ip with different names.  The issue is with Windows that can only allow one user at a time, thus cannot access as a root.